# How to create a row in a Excel sheet from R?

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I'm trying to add a title on each sheet of my Excel file using R (as all my data comes from R and I need to organize it in an Excel file). In order to do it, I'm using this function from 'xlsx' package, which I found [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r):

```
#++++++++++++++++++++++++
# Helper function to add titles
#++++++++++++++++++++++++
# - sheet : sheet object to contain the title
# - rowIndex : numeric value indicating the row to 
#contain the title
# - title : the text to use as title
# - titleStyle : style object to use for title
xlsx.addTitle<-function(sheet, rowIndex, title, titleStyle){
rows <-createRow(sheet,rowIndex=rowIndex)
sheetTitle <-createCell(rows, colIndex=1)
setCellValue(sheetTitle[[1,1]], title)
setCellStyle(sheetTitle[[1,1]], titleStyle)
}
```

The procedure is :
1) Create a new row
2) Create a cell in this row to contain the title.
3) Set the cell value.

In order to add a title on each sheet, I put this function in a loop:

```
# preparing for the loop 
wb <- loadWorkbook(file = "tmp_regioes.xlsx")
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
z <- length(titles)

# creating the style
SUB_TITLE_STYLE <- CellStyle(wb) + 
  Font(wb,  heightInPoints=14, 
       isItalic=TRUE, isBold=FALSE)

# loop
for (i in (1:z)) {

  sheet <- sheets[[i]]
  # Add sub title
  xlsx.addTitle(sheet, rowIndex=1, 
                title= paste0(titles[i]),
                titleStyle = SUB_TITLE_STYLE)
}
```

But it doesn't really create a new row; instead, it erases the content of my first row, which contains values (the column names of my tables).

Just to clarify, the file "tmp_regioes.xlsx" was created using the function WriteXLS, as I need to save 10 tables on the same file; and this function doesn't seem to have an option for saving the tables on the second row, for example.

If someone could help me with that, I would be very glad.
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have multiple options:

- You can use the parameter `startRow=2` in the `addDataFrame()` function when saving your data.
- You can use `rows <-createRow(sheet,rowIndex=1)` before placing your title on row 1.

The code below creates an example xlsx file as you mention from scratch. Hope this helps!

```
library(xlsx)

df = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(2,3,4))
titles = c( "A", "B","C")

wb<- createWorkbook(type = "xlsx")
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
z <- length(titles)

# creating the style
SUB_TITLE_STYLE <- CellStyle(wb) + 
  Font(wb,  heightInPoints=14, 
       isItalic=TRUE, isBold=FALSE)

# loop
for (i in (1:z)) {

  createSheet(wb, sheetName=paste0("Sheet",i))
  sheets <- getSheets(wb)
  sheet <- sheets[[i]]
  # Add sub title

  addDataFrame(df, sheet, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
               startRow = 1, startColumn = 1)  
  rows <-createRow(sheet,rowIndex=1)
  xlsx.addTitle(sheet, rowIndex=1, 
                title= paste0(titles[i]),
                titleStyle = SUB_TITLE_STYLE)


}

saveWorkbook(wb, "tmp.regioes.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, using the createRow function before placing the title didn't work. I will have to do it manually, with your first option, startRow=2 in addDataFrame().